# Capybara/CSS: How to find an input field by label AND value?

Tags: css, capybara

I need to fill in an input field in Capybara/RSpec.

```
<div class="form-group control_center_operators_name">    
  <label class="control-label"  
         for="control_center_operators_attributes_1477562669357_name">
    Name
  </label>       
  <input class="form-control"
       type="text" value=""          
       name="control_center[operators_attributes][1477562669357][name]" 
       id="control_center_operators_attributes_1477562669357_name" />
</div>
```

My problem is, that there are more fields like this, where the user can edit existing operators. e.g.

```
<div class="form-group control_center_operators_name">    
  <label class="control-label"  
         for="control_center_operators_attributes_0_name">
    Name
  </label>
  <input class="form-control" 
         type="text" value="ABC"          
         name="control_center[operators_attributes][0][name]" 
         id="control_center_operators_attributes_0_name" />
</div>
```

What I know about the field:

- it is labeled "Name"
- its value is "" (empty)

More restrictions:

- there are a total of 4 fields in this set (name, phone, email, homepage), that means I can't just take the one with `value=''` as there are 4 input fields matching this query.
- I can't use the id and name attributes, as you can see.

How can I fill the empty name, phone, email and homepage fields with Capybara/CSS?

Comment: Related: https://css-tricks.com/multiple-attribute-values/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Capybara method for finding a field is `#find_field`.  You can filter by value too  with the :with option

```
find_field('Name', with: '').set('new value to set')
```

Note that will match against the current value property of the element, which may not be the same as the value attribute if the value of the field has been changed since page load.  Another option is to scope to a wrapper element that would make the field unique and then find within that element.  For instance if each of these sets of fields was in a div with class of operator and you wanted to fill in the name in the the last operator set you could do

```
all('.operator', minimum: 1).last.fill_in('Name', with: 'new value to set')
```

**Update**: As of Capybara 3 `all` has waiting behavior by default so the `minimum` option would not be needed

```
all('.operator').last.fill_in('Name', with: 'new value to set')
```

Comment: Wow, you even guessed the scoping `div` right. I didn't do it exactly as you suggested but scoping it to the wrapping div was what I ended up doing. Thx.

Comment: Good answer because sometimes you want to get the input element first before sending any new text input.

Answer (score 2):

You can use xPath to find element that you need:

```
find(:xpath, "//label[contains(text(), 'Name')]/../input[@value='']")
```

If you want to use css maybe you can use `find_all` method that will find all empty fields, and you can fill them out one by one.

Also you can try: `find_field('Name', with: '')`. Documentation ([Capybara Docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders#find_field-instance_method)) says it looks at label, but I have doubts that it works as label is separate element. Could be that it depends on html structure, at least this hasn't worked for me.

Comment: find_field definitely can find by label text, and uses either the structure (label element wraps the field) or the `for` attribute on the label to find the field..  If you have an example where that doesn't work for you please file an issue on the Capybara project on github

Comment: your xpath expression didn't work out, but you definitely helped by pointing me in the right direction. I use xpath to find the right box (containing the 4 fields for the new operator) and use it in an `within do end` statement..